# resharper "cleanup code" vs. 'var' keyword

Tags: c#, resharper

I have an odd behavior with code clean up for c# in **visual studio 2008 Team Developer Edition**.

Whenever I clean up my code using "Full Cleanup", it replaces all variables declaration with explicit type declarations. But I have set the appropriate settings under "Inspection Severity", "Use var keyword when initializer explicitly declares type" and "use var keyword when possible" to "Show as Error"

Is there any other setting I need to set or is this a known bug?

Comment: sounds like desirable behaviour to me! How do you make it do that again?!?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a setting under the Code Cleanup section that specifies what Code Cleanup should do with `var` declarations.

In the ReSharper Menu, select Options.  At the bottom of the tree view, select Code Cleanup (in the Tools section).  Select a Code Cleanup preset on the right, and then look at the *Use 'var' in declaration* setting.  You probably want the *Replace direction* setting set to *Do not change*.

Comment: When I go to the Section "Code Cleanup" the right side remains blank. There are no profiles saved. I would always like to use "Full cleanup" but I can not change any settings for the profile Full cleanup because the list is empty.

Comment: You have to add a new profile of your own before you can edit the settings.

Answer (score 2):

This certainly looks like a bug to me. the var=> type usage works but the type usage => var does not on all of the devs machine here at work (R# 4.5). Posting feedback to R# now.

Comment: oh and ignore Mitch.. hes old skool.. go var! :p

Answer (score 2):

In Build 5.0.1659.36 there is a bug - "Use 'var' in declaration settings" are not respected.

Comment: Version 7 and its still there!

Comment: I'm using Build 8.2.0.2160 and it doesn't seem to respect my selection of 'Do not change' for 'Replace Direction' - it always swaps var out for the explicit type...very annoying!